# can't access element style properties

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I want to change some styles of my 'text' variable but somehow can't.

```
const bg = document.querySelector(".bg");
const text = document.querySelector('.loading-text');


let count = 0;

let interval = setInterval(blurr,30);

 function blurr() {
    if(count>99) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    text.innerHTML = `${count}%`;
    text.style //here is the problem
    count++;
};
```

Im new here, and new to javascript so go easy on me please :|

Comment: Please see [ask], then add some HTML to your code in a demo snippet.

Comment: `text.style` doesn't do anything. It accesses the style, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: If you want to change the style, you have to do something like `text.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do regarding the element styling?
Are you trying to get the current value or set it?

In order to get some CSS styling property you can do as follows:

```
var color = text.style.color;
```

If you are trying to set/change it, you can do as follows:

```
test.style.color = 'green';
```

See this documentation for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Edit:
From what I can tell OP is trying to set the opacity on the element.

```
text.style.opacity = 0.01 * count;
```

See this working here: https://jsfiddle.net/84pohswj/

But if that is the case I would suggest you use CSS animations instead. There much better option for this. And use JS to assign the animation class: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Yes, thats what i did.
But text.style doesnt work..

Comment: @benefiting_The_believer the code you have is incomplete. There is nothing that should work. You need to set the styling or get it. For opacity you need to do for example: text.style.opacity = 0.01 * count;  You also need to set the initial CSS for the element to opacity 0. But for this I would recommend animation.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to change your opacity to 0.5
here is the code

```js
text.style.opacity = "0.5";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I want to change the opacity.
I know there are other ways too, but im wondering why this one doesnt work.

If i do this:

const text = document.querySelector('.loading-text').style... here i can access the style for some reason

Comment: @benefiting_The_believer because in the code in your comment you are saving the values inside the "text" constant. In your code in the original post you are not doing anything to it. If you want to get the values, you need to do:  text = text.style;

Comment: @benefiting_The_believer you may have declared another constant named text in your code. instead of text, use textElement or textEl for short.